# Finding the maximum value of an array in log2 time in Verilog?

Tags: sorting, verilog

I have designed a 'sorter' that finds the maximum value of its input, which is 16 31-bit words.  In simulation, it works, but I am not sure if it will work in hardware (as it doesn't seem to be working on the FPGA as planned).  Can someone please let me know if this will work?  I am trying to save on resources, that is why I am trying to reuse the same register. Thank you...

```
module para_sort(clk, ready, array_in, out_max)
input clk, ready;
input [16*31-1:0] array_in;
output reg [30:0] out_max;
reg [30:0] temp_reg [0:15]
integer i, j;

always @ (posedge clk)
begin
   if(ready)
   begin
      for(j=0; j<16; j=j+1)
      begin
      temp_reg[j] <= array_in[31*(j+1)-1 -: 31];
      end
      i<=0;
      done<=0;
   end
   else
   begin
      if(i<4)
      begin
      for(j=0; j<16; j=j+1)
         if(temp_reg[j+1] > temp_reg[j]
         temp_reg[((j+2)>>1)-1] <= temp_reg[j+1]
         else
         temp_reg[((j+2)>>1)-1] <= temp_reg[j]

      i<=i+1;
      end
   end

   if(i == 4)
   begin
      out_max <= temp_reg[0];
      done <=1;
      i <= i + 1;
   end
   if(i == 5)
      done <=0;
end
endmodule
```

Sorry for the long code.  If you have any questions about the code, please let me know.

Comment: any synthesis warnings?

Comment: ... I don't *think* so. I am still new to this compiler.  it is a very large model so the warnings look a little like Greek to me.  I will look again.

Comment: There were some synthesis warnings, about a different part of the model. I accidentally multi drove a net. Perhaps this is my issue

Comment: This couldn't compile - are you sure you simulated it?

Comment: @EML Because he forgot to put some semicolons while posting the code

Comment: @EML And there are many other mistakes in the given code

Comment: @Lerbi It would be nice if you could post the exact code you used for synthesis, if it is not too long

Comment: @Lerbi The algorithm is also incorrect, increment the j in second for loop by 2 (j <= j + 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering the question, I assume that you do not have any problem with code syntax and semantics, and the module is part of the design so that you do not have problem with number of I/O pins, as it seems to be the case.

First of all, **the algorithm that has been used in this posted code is incorrect**. Maybe you meant something different, but this one is incorrect. The following code worked for me:

```
//The same code as you posted, but slight changes are made
//Maybe you have tried compiling this code and missed some points while posting
module para_sort(clk, ready, array_in, out_max, done);
input clk, ready;
input [16*31-1:0] array_in;
output reg [30:0] out_max;
output reg done;
reg [30:0] temp_reg [0:16];
integer i, j;

always @ (posedge clk)
begin
   if(ready)
   begin
      for(j=0; j<16; j=j+1)
      begin
      temp_reg[j] <= array_in[31*(j+1)-1 -: 31];
      end
      i<=0;
      done<=0;
   end
   else
   begin
      if(i<4)
      begin
      for(j=0; j<16; j=j+2)
        begin
         if(temp_reg[j+1] > temp_reg[j])
           temp_reg[((j+2)>>1)-1] <= temp_reg[j+1];
         else
           temp_reg[((j+2)>>1)-1] <= temp_reg[j];

        end // end of the for loop
        i<=i+1;
      end
   end

   if(i == 4)
   begin
      out_max <= temp_reg[0];
      done <=1;
      i <= i + 1;
   end
   if(i == 5)
      done <=0;
end
endmodule
```

If the above code does not solve the problem, then:

**The problem might be with timing.** In Quartus Prime software, there are netlist viewer tools (The same is true for Vivado). When you check the generated circuit, you can see paths with many combinational blocks and feedback (caused mostly by the second for loop). If the second for loop does not have enough time to complete execution in a single clock, you will loose synchronization and the results will be unpredictable.

So,

- **Try the above code first**
- **If the code does not solve your problem, then try FSM (with `case` and `if - else - if` statements ) even the code becomes longer or looks uglier (not user friendly), it is more FPGA hardware friendly.**

Comment: Timing analysis might also help you